# How do I keep my elderly mother from being driven by an alcoholic sibling?

Tags: united-states, guardianship

My brother is an alcoholic and proof of this has been accepted by the court system.  The Judge issured a “No Alcohol” prohibition in my mother's home and a stipulation that my mother not be given alcohol due to previous injuries/falls when drinking.  There is a new Guardian of my elderly mother that was appointed by the Judge.  No one is checking to see if my brother drinks when he visits and he drinks all the time, all involved purposely have a blind eye.  Although the Guardian stated she would not allow my brother to drive my mother, he has done so anyway and no one is stops him.  In fact, this Guardian just told my attorney that she feels certain my brother is not drinking based on no evidence at all.  What can I do to keep my mother safe?  Attempting to have police locate my brother for a DUI check never works, they never catch up with him.

Comment: Restraining order?

Comment: We went this route last June as was advised by police & adult protective services to seek this.  The Judge was crooked and did nothing at the final protective order hearing  My Mom's home health aides were fired because they were willing to testify that day and in Guardianship case concerning abuse.